# Attributing row name of irregular number of rows (populations)

Tags: r, population

I've been given this to do by the GENELAND tutorial to give population names to a dataset of populations of 60 individuals :

```
pop.mbrship1<-rep(c(1,2,3), each=60)
```

Nevertheless, my dataset comprises 10 populations of irregular sizes to which i would give the names of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and the distribution of my individuals (represented by one row each) would be : 
1:24,25:39,40:58,59:79,80:103,104:126,127:147,148:171,172:191,192:214

I'd be tempted to use each population number as number of repeats which would make it

```
pop.mbrship1<-rep[c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), each=c(24,15,19,21,24,23,21,24,20,23)]
```

Or try their distribution...

```
pop.mbrship1<-rep[c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
c(1:24,25:39,40:58,59:79,80:103,104:126,127:147,148:171,172:191,192:214)]
```

In both case, R gives me Error: unexpected '>' in ">"

I'm sure i'm really close to having it work but i've spent a shameful amount of time on this and i'd defenetly need a hand. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It sounds like you're copying the console prompt from your tutorial into the console. You don't need to type `>` or copy `>` when you're typing into the console. Try it for yourself, just type `>` at the console and hit enter and you'll see the same error.

Comment: `pop.mbrship1 <- rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), c(24,15,19,21,24,23,21,24,20,23))`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at the geneland tutorial and I see that they have `>` at the beginning of the lines that you're copying/editing.

[image]

You are copying everything including the console pointer `>` all you need to copy/paste is :

```
# replicates each element 60 times
pop.mbrship1 <- rep(c(1,2,3),each=60) 

# replicates each element, respectively
pop.mbrship2 <- rep(c(1,2,3),times=c(60,40,30))
```

Your answer is what Henrik said above, without a preceding`>`.

```
pop.mbrship1 <- rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), c(24,15,19,21,24,23,21,24,20,23))

# same as
pop.mbrship1 <- rep(c(...),times=c(...))
```